# Socket: Java-Client to C#-Server, missing some data

Tags: c#, java, sockets

i wrote a Simple Socket Server in C# and works quite well.I use the connection to send some *.xml Files from one device (mobile Phone, PC) to another. I have 3 Different Clients, C#,Delphi and Java. The Server is working with the C# and the Delphi, but with the Java Client it's not working as expected.

The Problem with the java client is, that i'm just receiving around 3/4 of the Data from the sended xml File. I watched the Debugger and every charakter of the Document is send by the Java client, but it's not received. It doesn't matter how long the Document is, there is always something missing. I looked for some hours now to find i reason, but i couldn't. Maybe u guys can help me.

Server:

```
public void WaitForClient(String filepath)
        {

int bytesRcvd;
            Byte[] rcvBuffer;
            string receivedMessage = "";

            try
            {
                {
                    // Generiere eine Client Verbindung
                    //client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    client = listener.AcceptSocket();
                    //netStream = client.GetStream();
                    SetTexts(powercomConsole, "Handling client - ");
                    //Console.Write("Handling client - ");
                    int z = 0;
                    //int totalBytesEchoed = 0;
                    rcvBuffer = new byte[64];
                    //while ((bytesRcvd = netStream.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRcvd = client.Receive(rcvBuffer);
                        for (int i = 0; i < rcvBuffer.Length; i++)
                        {
                            receivedMessage += (rcvBuffer[i] != 0) ? Convert.ToChar(rcvBuffer[i]).ToString() : "";
                            z++;
                            if (!receivedMessage.Equals(""))
                                Console.WriteLine("hans");
                            //receivedMessage += Convert.ToChar(rcvBuffer[i]);
                        }
                        rcvBuffer = new byte[64];
                    } while (bytesRcvd != 0);
                    WriteFile(filepath, receivedMessage);
                    SetTexts(powercomConsole, "Generated File written to " + filepath);
                    //Console.WriteLine("New File written to " + filepath);

                    // Schließe den Socket. Wir haben den Clienten erfolgreich abgewickelt
                    CloseServer();
                    SetTexts(powercomConsole, "Server closed");
                    //Console.WriteLine("Server closed");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                //netStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Client:

```
public boolean sendByteBuffer(String profilename) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = fileToByteBuffer(profilename);
    for (int i = 0; i < fSize; i++)
    {
        char hans = (char) buffer.get();
        out.print(hans);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fChan.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    try {
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private ByteBuffer fileToByteBuffer(String filepath) {
        ByteBuffer mBuf = null;

        try {
            fIn = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            fChan = fIn.getChannel();
            fSize = fChan.size();
            mBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) fSize);
            fChan.read(mBuf);
            mBuf.rewind();
            // for (int i = 0; i < fSize; i++)
            // System.out.print((char) mBuf.get());
            // fChan.close();
            // fIn.close();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return mBuf;
    }
```

This is the `fileToByteBuffer()` Method i use in the `sendByteBuffer` Method

Thank you in advace ;)

Comment: on your client, whats 'fSize'...?

Comment: fSize is the size of the FileChannel, maybe you can use the fileToByteArray() mehtod aswell

Comment: I've done almost this same thing and ran into issues where my C# code could just call @Read()@ and it would get all the bytes, but I had to call Java's @read()@ over and over until I had all the bytes.  I had to make it so the reader knew how many bytes it would read and read until it got everything.  I horked it up by passing a Content-Length type header line, but it felt a little dirty.